# How do I combine two fetch requests to get the information I need?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am writing a site with information about films. I need to get my hands on genres. But the problem is this. In the request, where all the main information is located, the genres are indicated by id. I need to make another request where there are these id and genre names. In a Vue component, I made a for loop. With it, I show basic information besides genres. How can I combine the two queries?

My Code:

movies.js

```
export default {
  actions: {
    async getPopularFilms({ commit }) {
      const res_movies = await fetch(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=d502a3d84eb533756ec099ef127a2acd&language=en-US&page=1'
      );
      const { results } = await res_movies.json();
      commit('updateFilms', results);

      // Fetch genres
      const res_genres = await fetch(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=d502a3d84eb533756ec099ef127a2acd&language=en-US'
      );
      const { genres } = await res_genres.json();

      let ids = [];
      let genres_ids = [];
      for (let id = 0; id < results.length; id++) {
        ids.push(results[id].genre_ids);
      }
      for (let id = 0; id < genres.length; id++) {
        genres_ids.push(genres[id]);
      }
      console.log(ids);
      console.log(genres_ids);
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    updateFilms(state, films) {
      state.popular = films;
    },
    updateGenres(state, genres) {
      state.genres = genres;
    },
  },
  state: {
    popular: [],
    genres: [],
  },
  getters: {
    returnFilms(state) {
      return state.popular;
    },
    returnGenres(state) {
      return state.genres;
    },
  },
};
```

PopularMovies.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container mx-auto px-4 pt-8">
    <div class="popular-movies">
      <h2
        class="uppercase tracking-wider text-lg text-orange-500 font-semibold"
      >
        Popular movies
      </h2>
      <div
        class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-4"
      >
        <div v-for="movies in returnFilms" :key="movies.id" class="mt-8">
          <img
            :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200' + movies.poster_path"
            alt="poster"
            class="hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
          />
          <div class="mt-2">
            <p class="text-lg mt-2 hover:text-gray-300">{{ movies.title }}</p>
            <div class="flex items-center mt1 text-sm text-gray-400">
              <svg class="fill-current text-orange-500 w-4" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <g data-name="Layer 2">
                  <path
                    d="M17.56 21a1 1 0 01-.46-.11L12 18.22l-5.1 2.67a1 1 0 01-1.45-1.06l1-5.63-4.12-4a1 1 0 01-.25-1 1 1 0 01.81-.68l5.7-.83 2.51-5.13a1 1 0 011.8 0l2.54 5.12 5.7.83a1 1 0 01.81.68 1 1 0 01-.25 1l-4.12 4 1 5.63a1 1 0 01-.4 1 1 1 0 01-.62.18z"
                    data-name="star"
                  ></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <span class="ml-1">{{ movies.vote_average * 10 }}%</span>
              <span class="mx-2">|</span>
              <span>{{ movies.release_date }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="text-gray-300 text-sm">aaa</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Popular Movies',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['returnFilms']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getPopularFilms']),
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.getPopularFilms();
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.text-orange-500 {
  color: #ed8936;
}
</style>
```

Screenshots
[image]

[image]

My gets requests:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=d502a3d84eb533756ec099ef127a2acd&language=en-US&page=1

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=d502a3d84eb533756ec099ef127a2acd&language=en-US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the genreIds transformed to their name, within results.

Try this. I cannot test it unfortunately. I am on mobile.

```
async getPopularFilms({ commit }) {
      const res_movies = await fetch(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=d502a3d84eb533756ec099ef127a2acd&language=en-US&page=1'
      );
      const { results } = await res_movies.json();
      commit('updateFilms', results);

      // Fetch genres
      const res_genres = await fetch(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=d502a3d84eb533756ec099ef127a2acd&language=en-US'
      );
      const { genres } = await res_genres.json();

      const filmsWithGenres = results.map( ({genre_ids, ...rest}) => ({...rest, genre_ids: genre_ids.map(id => genres.find(genre => genre.id === id).name )}) )

      console.log(filmsWithGenres);
    },
```

Comment: ExplanationSo, I'm using three things here. Arrow functions `() => ({})`, `Array.map()` and `Array.find()`.

Comment: Map loops over every item in an array, and return an array with each returned item. The arrow function within map function, received the item being looped over inside it's (first) (). The part after the arrow (=>) is the return value to the (new) array. Which is the name, which is found within the genres array with Array.find().

Comment: Find does something similar to map, it loops over every value within the array, until it finds the item (within the array) that matches the condition (also known as the test). Find returns the item matched, which is an object containing the id and name of the genre. Thus you can get the name with .name

Comment: Was problem with "find" function. Vscode automtic import "find" from 'core.js'. I was remove import. And code was start